# Adding a line of code changes the memory address of a variable

Tags: c, pointers, memory

The original code is :

```
int main(){
int sam= 19;
int *pSam= &sam;
printf("Address \t name \t value\n");
printf("%p \t %s \t %d\n", pSam, "sam", sam);

return 0;
```

The memory address of sam is shown as= 0028FF18.

However If I change nothing about the variable, and just add another line of code above the 'return 0;' which is:

```
 printf("%p \t %s \t %p", &pSam, "sam", pSam);
```

And then run the program, the memory address of sam changes to 0028FF1C, even though I just printed out some basic stuff.

Why is that?

Comment: How do you know the address of `sam` in your first example if you do not print it because you add the `printf("%p \t %s \t %p", &pSam, "sam", pSam)` only in the second example?

Comment: May be in the first case the compiler optimizes away `int *pSam= &sam;` so there's one less variable on the stack.

Comment: @ouah I included pSam which essentially prints out the memory address sam.

Comment: @mustaccio when you say optimize what you mean? The address is 4 bytes larger than the original: (from 0028FF18 to 0028FF1C ) The stack addressing **grows** from small to large.

Comment: @simplicisveritatis: Could be it allocates stack frames in 8 byte increments. In the first case, `sam` is the only 32 bit variable in that block. In the second case, it's the second 32 variable in that block, so it's at a higher address than before. Could also be an upward growing stack, for all we know - `0x0028FF1C` isn't all that high in a 32 bit address space.

Comment: You do need to cast the pointers you pass to `printf` to `(void *)` -> check the standard (says something about _"the pointer shall be of type `void *`"_

Comment: Could this translation in address be caused by the fact that you are passing a variable by value, so it's copied.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, this is almost certainly about optimization.

This:

```
int main() {
   int sam = 19;
   int *pSam = &sam;
   printf("Address \t name \t value\n");
   printf("%p \t %s \t %d\n", pSam, "sam", sam);

   return 0;
}
```

is essentially equivalent to this:

```
int main() {
   int sam = 19;
   /* int *pSam = &sam; */
   printf("Address \t name \t value\n");
   /* printf("%p \t %s \t %d\n", pSam, "sam", sam); */
   printf("%p \t %s \t %d\n", &sam, "sam", sam);

   return 0;
}
```

In other words, it can be done without the variable `pSam` at all, and accordingly, a smart compiler will optimize that variable away. Depending on the processor, even without optimizing it away it may be able to store everything in registers rather than allocate storage on the stack.

But, if you want to take the *address* of `pSam`, then obviously it cannot be optimized away or put in a register, because if you do either of these things then it's not going to have an address. So when you do this you force the compiler to allocate memory for it, almost certainly on the stack, here. And, in this case, it looks like when you do that the address of `sam` - also by necessity allocated on the stack, since you also take its address and output it - is changing as a result, probably because your compiler is allocating `pSam` on the stack before `sam`.

Comment: Why the downvote? I think your answer is more expressive than mine's :).

Answer (score 0):

Although it's not so obvious, what *may* cause this is a compiler optimization being invalidated.

In your original code

```
int main() {
    int sam = 19;
    int *pSam= &sam;

    printf("Address \t name \t value\n");
    printf("%p \t %s \t %d\n", pSam, "sam", sam);

    return 0;
}
```

You may notice that the address of the `pSam` variable is *never* needed, so the compiler may perfectly optimize that variable away, resulting in a smaller (by a few bytes...) stack.

Now, when you add in the other line in the mix.

```
printf("%p \t %s \t %p", &pSam, "sam", pSam);
```

The compiler optimization *gets invalidated*, that is, its assertion (the address of `pSam` is never used) is no longer valid, so the optimization is not perfomable. This implies that the variable `pSam` is now not optimized away, and is now actually present in stack space, thus pushing, shifting, or otherwise modifying the addresses of other stack variables in the process.